# Eliminate punctuations and whitespace

Tags: c++, algorithm, string-parsing, stdstring, input-filtering

I am new to c++ programming and would like to write a program which has the following requirement:

Given a text consists of

- words
- letters
- numbers
- punctuations, and
- whitespaces.

Filter out any characters that not in the range of `0..9`, `a..z` or `A..Z`.

This means that when I typed in:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!
```

The output will be:

```
Thequickbrownfoxjumpsoverthelazydog
```

I have typed the following codes and try to run it and the outcome is fine. However, when I submitted it onto another c++ platform for checking the validity, there is no output to be generated.

I am so confused... Please help if you could. Thank you very much to you all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (!((line[i] >= 'a' && line[i] <= 'z') || (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i] <= 'Z') || (line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9')))
        {
            line[i] = '\0';
        }
    }
    cout << line;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not erasing any character. You substitute `\0`, which commonly has a special meaning - it marks end of string. Your "other C++ platform" could parse strings this way and it concludes it received empty string. Try [`erase(i, 1)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) in your `if` instead.

Comment: You mistake is thinking that `line[i] = '\0';` erases a character. It doesn't, it just replaces one character with another. `std::string` has a method `erase` for erasing characters, try using that.

Comment: Do you mean by changing the line[i] = '\0]; to erase(i, 1) ? I do not quite understand what you guys mean

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the characters other than *letters* and *digits*, the better choice would be using [erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

1. Use
   [`std::isalnum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalnum)
   to check the character in the string is either an *alphabet* or a
   *numeric*. If you pack it into a unary predicate(*lambda function*), you can apply to the following algorithm function.
2. Using
   [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove),
   and the above-mentioned predicate, collect all characters in the
   string, which had to be removed.
3. Lastly, using
   [`std::string::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)
   remove all the characters which have been collected by
   `std::remove_if`.

Something like as follows:
<kbd>[See a demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wWCaZvyir5Fs7gdl)</kbd>

```
#include <cctype>     // std::isalnum
#include <algorithm>  // std::remove_if

std::string str{ "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog!" };

// predicate to check the charectors
const auto check = [](const char eachCar)->bool { return !std::isalnum(eachCar); };

// collect the chars which needed to be removed from the string
const auto charsToRemove = std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), check);

// erase them out
str.erase(charsToRemove, str.end());
```

---

<sub>**Disclaimer**: The above solution does not cover OP's concern(@john has explained it well in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667419/eliminate-punctuations-and-whitespace/53667911#53667911)), rather it could be helpful for future readers.</sub>

Comment: So what chance do you think the OP has of understanding the above code?

Comment: Well I suppose it a common issue, do you answer the question for the OP or for anyone else who might be reading. Personally I always answer for the OP when it's basic stuff like this.

Comment: @john Yes... I prefer always to answer the concern issue. When it comes to alternative shortcuts(i.e, using C++ algorithums), I rather go for answering using them. As you mentioned, for future readers, that might be helpful. Sometimes, OP even can inform himself about the std facilities available what he/she about to reinvent.(IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

Your code just replaces one character with another. The simple way to erase characters from a string is to use the `erase` method. Something like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string line;
    getline(cin, line);
    for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); )
    {
        if (!((line[i] >= 'a' && line[i]<='z') || (line[i] >= 'A' && line[i]<='Z')||(line[i] >= '0' && line[i]<='9')))
        {
            line.erase(i, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    cout << line; 
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the code only adds one to `i` when we don't erase a character, otherwise you'd skip the character after the one erased because the string is now one shorter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are great and the answer is easy to understand for one like me. However, there is still one problem which is that there is a space is indented in the output? How should I delete the indentation?

Comment: @ChunTsz I'm not sure, what's the input and what's the output that you see? There could easily be a bug in the above code, I haven't tested anything.

Comment: @john I have solved the problem but another one came out and I am unable to handle..  for example, if the input is : abcdefg /n hijklmn , then now the program outputs only abcdefg but no hijklmn append behind the former. How should I amend the codes? Can I get some hints?

Comment: You need to read multiple lines, `getline` reads only one line, so you need some sort of loop around your code. E.g. `while (getline(cin, line)) { ... }`

Comment: @john sorry John. To be honest, I wrote part of these codes under the coaching by my friend. Do you mean I should add a while loop to the getline function only?

Comment: Try both ways and think about what the difference is when you run the program. Programming isn't magic you can figure it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`\0` is the end of a string, so when you use this, you are cutting off your string at the first occurence.

You'd better remove that char from your array, but then I'd advise you to go from the end back to the beginning:

Pseudo-code:

```
for i = size(line)-1 back to i = 0:
  if line[i] in ('a'-'z', 'A'-'Z', ...):
    for j = i to size(line)-1:
      line[j] = line[j+1]
   reduce_by_the_last_character(line)
```